# Creating a column that counts how many times a variable appears across the columns in R

Tags: r

Lets say I have this data set:

```
  col1 col2 
1   2    1 
2   1    1 
3   1    2 
4   1    2 
5   1    2 
6   1    1 
7   2    1 
8   2    2
```

How would I go about creating a column that counts the number of times either "1" or "2" appears across the columns, such that it looks like this:

```
  col1 col2 count_1 count_2
1   2    1     1      1
2   1    1     2      0
3   1    2     1      1
4   1    2     1      1
5   1    2     1      1
6   1    1     2      0
7   2    1     1      1
8   2    2     0      2
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `rowSums` on a logical matrix created with value to be compared by looping over those values

```
df1[paste0("count_", seq_along(df1))] <- lapply(1:2, 
     function(x) rowSums(df1 == x))
```

-output

```
> df1
  col1 col2 count_1 count_2
1    2    1       1       1
2    1    1       2       0
3    1    2       1       1
4    1    2       1       1
5    1    2       1       1
6    1    1       2       0
7    2    1       1       1
8    2    2       0       2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), col2 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible  to pick out specific columns to count across? The actual data set I'm using has multiple columns that aren't relevant for me to count.

Comment: @user20409556 yes that is easier.  just subset i.e. `nm1 <- c("col1", "col2"); df1[paste0("count_", seq_along(df1[nm1]))] <- lapply(1:2, 
     function(x) rowSums(df1[nm1] == x))`

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyverse`-style:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(1:2, ~ transmute(df1, "count_{.x}" := rowSums(across(everything()) == .x))))

#   col1 col2 count_1 count_2
# 1    2    1       1       1
# 2    1    1       2       0
# 3    1    2       1       1
# 4    1    2       1       1
# 5    1    2       1       1
# 6    1    1       2       0
# 7    2    1       1       1
# 8    2    2       0       2
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to pick out specific columns to count across? The actual data set I'm using has multiple columns that aren't relevant for me to count.

Comment: Yes! in the `across` call; instead of everything(), you can put whatever fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting the numbers 1 to n in the specified columns:

```
n = 2L
inp_col = sprintf("col%d", 1L:2L)
df[sprintf("count_%d", 1L:n)] = t(apply(df[inp_col], 1L, tabulate, nbins = n))
#   col1 col2 count_1 count_2
# 1    2    1       1       1
# 2    1    1       2       0
# 3    1    2       1       1
# 4    1    2       1       1
# 5    1    2       1       1
# 6    1    1       2       0
# 7    2    1       1       1
# 8    2    2       0       2
```

Data:

```
df = data.frame(
  col1 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  col2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)
)
```